# Unable to install anything from AppCenter

Tags: appcenter, apps, install

In AppCenter when I click to download a piece of software, it does this: "starting.. waiting..." then nothing. It doesn't install or anything.

What can I do to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Issue resolved when I restarted my computer.

Comment: Can you post this comment like an answer of your question, and later mark it as the approved one in order to be helpful for anybody who gets the same problem later?